# Unlist a singleton list to an atom in kdb

Tags: kdb

Many times I come across a singleton list like

```
,1b 
,0Nd
```

and in order to convert the singleton list to an atom I always use first operator.
Example:

```
q)a: enlist 0Nd
q)a
,0Nd
q)b:null a
q)b
,1b
q)first a
0Nd
q)first b
1b
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to convert a singleton list to an atom but I'm not able to find that. Can someone please let me know how to unlist a singleton list to an atom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, `first` is the best operator. You could index into the list, but that will likely have at best equal performance.

If you're concerned with reliably converting only singleton lists into atoms, you could use the following

```
q)conform:{$[0< type x;$[1=count x;first x;x];x]}
q)conform a
0Nd
q)conform 3i
3i
q)conform 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

What is the concern you have with `first`, it's about as simple and easy as you can get

Comment: I don't have any concern with first. Since the primary job of first in not to convert from singleton list to atom because of which I wanted to understand if there is any operator or way whose primary work is to convert from singleton list to atom. Thanks for quick response!

Comment: kdb operators are very overloaded, there are few operators with a 'primary job'. In this case I would disagree, the conversion of an enlisted atom to an atom invovles extracting the first item of the list, that's what first is for. kdb development is strongly results driven, don't shy away from using the most efficient operators that work for a given situation.

Comment: Completely agreed with you. Thanks!

Comment: One other consideration of first versus direct indexing is that first does not require you to know the type of the entry, so no need to worry about how to index into it.

Comment: If it's a list then indexing to 0 will always yield a result, and will extract the first item even if it itself is of type 0h. However, if the object is a numeric atom, it will result in attempting to write to a handle

Answer (score 1):

To generalise, if given a singleton array, the following function extracts its sole atom:

```
q)atom:{if[1=count a:(raze/)x;:first a];'"atom"}
q)@[atom;;"cannot"] each (`a;enlist enlist `a;();enlist 1 2;enlist enlist 1 2; enlist ())
`a
`a
"cannot"
"cannot"
"cannot"
"cannot"
```

Comment: Interesting solution.